# file_put_contents() store files outside the public folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to save file **inside public folder** using this ***file_put_contents()*** but in local it working fine it save file in public folder **but in live server it save outside the public folder.**

```
file_put_contents($lesson->id.'test'.$i.'.mp3', $resp->getAudioContent());
```

[image]

my local URL contains public word but live URL is without public word
Thanks for any help

Comment: In what directory is your script? In the same directory?

Comment: It depends on the document root configuration, save yourself the trouble and use the `Storage` facade for saving files or use `public_path('path/to/your/file')` if you really want to use the public root.

Comment: Why do you use `file_put_contents` in a Laravel context? Why not use `Storage::put`?

Comment: You have to specifify the path. The default is to save where the current script is executed : file_put_contents($path . '/' . $lesson->id.'test'.$i.'.mp3', $resp->getAudioContent());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not declare the root folder of your application the same as the server.
To put your file in the public folder on the server do

```
file_put_contents('public/'.$lesson->id.'test'.$i.'.mp3', $resp->getAudioContent());
```

You can also use the absolute path of your public folder to make it work on **both** your local installation and the server

```
file_put_contents(public_path($lesson->id.'test'.$i.'.mp3'), $resp->getAudioContent());
```